# Generating tuples variables in ansible templates

Tags: ansible

I'm trying to setup a playbook to deploy an influxdb cluster. Everything works fine except that we use [INfluxDB Cluster Client](http://influxdb-python.readthedocs.org/en/latest/api-documentation.html#influxdbclusterclient)

I am generating a production.py file which is read by our script.

InfluxdbClusterClient is waiting for a tuple to list all influx servers :

```
'hosts': [('fr-influxdb-prod-1', 8086), ('fr-influxdb-prod-2', 8086), ('fr-influxdb-prod-3', 8086)],
```

I am trying to generate those tuples from ansible variables but I don't know how to to dat. I tried:

```
/ Variables /
influxdb_hosts: [('fr-influxdb-prod-1', 8086), ('fr-influxdb-prod-2', 8086), ('fr-influxdb-prod-3', 8086)]

/ Template / 
....
'hosts': {{influxdb_hosts}},
...
```

Unfortunately it doesn't work as expected as Ansible is transforming the tuple in list (ie `[('fr-influxdb-prod-1', 8086), ('fr-influxdb-prod-2', 8086), ('fr-influxdb-prod-3', 8086)]` becomes `["('fr-influxdb-prod-1'", "8086)", "('fr-influxdb-prod-2'"," 8086)"," ('fr-influxdb-prod-3'"," 8086)]"`

Do you see what i'm doing wrong ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use folded block scalar to inform Ansible that the argument is a string which shouldn't be parsed:

```
influxdb_hosts: >
  [('fr-influxdb-prod-1', 8086), ('fr-influxdb-prod-2', 8086), ('fr-influxdb-prod-3', 8086)],
```

This is generated destination file:

```
'hosts': [('fr-influxdb-prod-1', 8086), ('fr-influxdb-prod-2', 8086), ('fr-influxdb-prod-3', 8086)],
```

Comment: Unfortunately ansible keep parsing my variable. It now renderer as : `'hosts': \"[('fr-influxdb-prod-1', 8086), ('fr-influxdb-prod-2', 8086), ('fr-influxdb-prod-3', 8086)]\",`

Comment: @AlexGrs I didn't check how this variable will be parsed when inside of a template. I've edited my response with a better solution.