# A better way to organize user names, passwords, and other options in bash

Tags: bash, ansible

I have a [bash script](https://github.com/lyenliang/CreateLinuxAccountWithAnsible) that uses ansible to create multiple users on an AWS EC2.

One thing that I feel bad about the script is this structure in `config.sh`:

```
username=(
  user1
  user2
  user3
)
passwd=(
  password1
  password2
  password3
)

become_sudoer=(
  true
  true
  false
)
```

This configuration means that my script will use anisble to create a user  with name=`user1`, password=`password1`, and has sudo privilege on the EC2 instance. And another user with name=`user2`, password=`password2`, and has sudo privilege. ...

When the number of users to be created becomes large (let's say 10), I might accidentally assign `password8` to user `user7`. Because I might mistakenly treat `password8` as the 7th row in `passwd` variable. This is something I want to avoid.

Are there any better structure in bash to avoid this problem?

In other programming languages such as python, I can use dictionaries to avoid this problem. For example:

```
user1 = {'name': 'user1', 'password': 'password1', 'become_sudoer': True}
user2 = {'name': 'user2', 'password': 'password2', 'become_sudoer': True}
user3 = {'name': 'user3', 'password': 'password3', 'become_sudoer': False}
...
```

This structure binds `user1` to `password1`, which makes me less likely to assign `password8` to `user7`.

Comment: Something like this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34887828/generating-tuples-variables-in-ansible-templates

Comment: Maybe you could use an associative array as described here to structure it a litte bit better https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/437680/set-data-structure-equivalent-in-bash-shell. You then could use user1[password]=... and put all userX maps into one list to iterate it. One question: Why do you tagged your question with ansible? Theres nothing related to ansible in your question as far as I can see it.

Comment: @StefanWegener, Because I thought that maybe I could use ansible related commands instead of bash to create accounts on an linux machine. That why I tagged my question with ansible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not replace your `config.sh` with a YAML file `users.yml`?

```
users:
  user1:
    password: "XXX"
    sudoers: true

  user2
    password: "YYY"
    sudoers: true
…
```

Then in your `createUser.yml` play book you add a tasks to lead the variables:

```
- name: Include the input for the users management
  include_vars: users.yml
```

And update your `user` task to loop on your users:

```
    - name: Create users
      user:
        name: "{{ item.key }}"
        password: "{{ item.value.password | default(omit) }}"
        state: present
        shell: "{{ item.value.shell | default ("/bin/bash") }}"
        system: no             # Defaults to no
        createhome: yes        # Defaults to yes
        home: "{{ item.value.home | default ("/home/" + username) }}"
      with_dict: "{{ users }}"
```

Then of course you will have to remove your loop `for` from the `run.sh` script… But BTW, I would merge the tasks from `giveSudoPrivilege.yml` into the same playbook (Move everything in `createUser.yml`). So adding to add the user in the wheel group, you could use the same loop and adding a when clause like this:

```
- name: Add sudoers users to wheel group
      user: 
        name: {{ item.key }}
        groups: wheel
        append: yes
        state: present
       with_dict: "{{ users }}"
       when: item.value.sudoers == true
```

Or even maybe merge the two `user` task by putting the 2 following arguments in the first `user` task:

```
        groups: "{% if item.value.sudoers==true %}wheel{% else %}{% endif %}"
        append: "{% if item.value.sudoers==true %}yes{% else %}no{% endif %}"
```

That way, you could even add easily other stuff like `shell` or `home` attribute. You could also imagine having an `user_passord.yml` file with the password encrypted with Vault.

Comment: Thank you. Using yaml is far more readable than using my `config.sh`.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using a [vault](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/vault.html) with the format from the [Salstack users pillars](https://gist.github.com/UtahDave/3785738#file-saltsample_09252012_01-L22-L45), for example, create the "vault" like this:

```
ansible-vault create my-users.yml
```

Then use this format:

```
users:
  alice:
    fullname: Alice
    password: xxx
    pub_ssh_keys:
      - ssh-rsa AAAA

  bob:
    fullname: Bob
    password: xxx
    pub_ssh_keys:
      - ssh-rsa AAAA
```